# How to adjust the div area after closing the another div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Twitter bootstrap framework.

I have a two Div containers in a main container. In each div container having three divs, I have placed close button in the div. When I close the top div, bottom div comes up, like this if i close all the divs the right container should come left side.

HTML code

```
<div id="DashboardCanvas">
 <div class="colDashboard ui-sortable col-one">
  <div id="one"><a id="oneClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
  <div id="two"><a id="twoClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
  <div id="three"><a id="threeClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
 </div>
 <div class="colDashboard ui-sortable col-two">
  <div id="four"><a id="fourClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
  <div id="five"><a id="fiveClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
  <div id="six"><a id="sixClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#oneClose").click(function(e) {
 $("#one").hide();
});

$("#twoClose").click(function(e) {
 $("#two").hide();
});

$("#threeClose").click(function(e) {
 $("#three").hide();
});

$("#fourClose").click(function(e) {
 $("#four").hide();
});

$("#fiveClose").click(function(e) {
 $("#five").hide();
});

$("#sixClose").click(function(e) {
 $("#six").hide();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can u please give fiddle .. ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/byx64/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, you love write code ? Use class if all div are the same...

```
<div id="DashboardCanvas">
 <div class="colDashboard ui-sortable col-one">
  <div id="one" class="number"><a id="oneClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
  <div id="two" class="number"><a id="twoClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
  <div id="three" class="number"><a id="threeClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
 </div>
 <div class="colDashboard ui-sortable col-two">
  <div id="four" class="number"><a id="fourClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
  <div id="five" class="number"><a id="fiveClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
  <div id="six" class="number"><a id="sixClose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and your JS

```
$('.number').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    // do what you want when element is clicked
  })
});
```

For more, if i click on the div "one" she disapear ?